# Show Alert dialog box while proceeding to next page in android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have 4 button options without clicking any one  of the options and  I am proceeding to next page it should show an alert dialog box.

if(btnOpt_1.equals(btnOpt_1)&&btnOpt_2.equals(btnOpt_2)&&btnOpt_3.equals(btnOpt_3)||btnOpt_4.equals(btnOpt_4)||btnOpt_5.equals(btnOpt_5)){

```
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Feedback.this);

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("OOPs");

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("You can't proceed without selecting");

    // Setting Icon to Dialog


    // Setting Positive "Yes" Button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {

        // Write your code here to invoke YES event
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on YES", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    // Setting Negative "NO" Button



    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}

}
```

Comment: Try to do it in onResume().

Answer (score 1):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
    private Button btnOpt_1;
    private Button btnOpt_2;
    private Button btnOpt_3;
    private Button btnOpt_4;
    private Button btnNext;
    private int selectedOption;

        btnOpt_1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOpt_1);
        btnOpt_2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOpt_2);
        btnOpt_3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOpt_3);
        btnOpt_4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOpt_4);
        btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);

        selectedOption=0;
        btnOpt_1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                selectedOption=1;
            }
        });

        btnOpt_2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                selectedOption=2;
            }
        });

        btnOpt_3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                selectedOption=3;
            }
        });

        btnOpt_4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                selectedOption=4;
            }
        });

        btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(selectedOption==0){
                    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Feedback.this);

                    // Setting Dialog Title
                    alertDialog.setTitle("OOPs");

                    // Setting Dialog Message
                    alertDialog.setMessage("You can't proceed without selecting");

                    // Setting Icon to Dialog


                    // Setting Positive "Yes" Button
                    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {

                            // Write your code here to invoke YES event
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on YES", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

                    // Setting Negative "NO" Button



                    // Showing Alert Message
                    alertDialog.show();
                }else{
                    // write your code here and you also track which option button is click using  selectedOption value.
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ... run your alert dialog on ui thread ...

```
    if(btnOpt_1.equals(btnOpt_1)&&btnOpt_2.equals(btnOpt_2)&&btnOpt_3.equals(btnOpt_3)||btnOpt_4.equals(btnOpt_4)||btnOpt_5.equals(btnOpt_5)){

runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

@override
public void run() {

if(!isFinishing()){
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Feedback.this);

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("OOPs");

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("You can't proceed without selecting");

    // Setting Icon to Dialog


    // Setting Positive "Yes" Button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {

        // Write your code here to invoke YES event
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on YES", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    // Setting Negative "NO" Button



    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}
});
}
```